# Ruby/Rails: dynamically change attribute in shared partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

This should be a layup for someone...

I'm trying to change a form field's attribute depending on which controller/model is calling the partial containing the form fields...

The issue (below) is with `parent_id`... which references one of two columns in a dogs table.  It needs to either be `kennel_id` or `master_id` depending on which view this partial is being rendered in.

Not comfortable enough, yet, with Ruby/Rails language/syntax/tools to dynamically change this without getting bogged down in `if/else` statements.

I'm calling a shared partial and passing in a local variable:

```
= render "dogs/form", :parent => @kennel
```

or

```
= render "dogs/form", :parent => @master
```

In the partial I'd like to:

```
  = form_for ([parent, target.dogs.build]) do |f|
    = render "shared/error_messages", :target => parent

    .field
        = f.label :name
        = f.text_field :name
    .field
        = f.hidden_field :parent_id  ###  <= PROBLEM
    .actions
        = f.submit 'Save'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thinking out loud:

I don't know if the `parent`-models have the proper names for it, but you could do something like:

```
= f.hidden_field "#{parent.class.name.underscore}_id"
```

But that doesn't look right. So, why not pass it as an argument?

```
= render "dogs/form", :parent => @master, :foreign_key => :master_id
```

Or, create aliases on the dog model to handle some sort of dynamic delegation:

```
class Dog
  def parent_id=(parent_id)
    case parent.class
    when Master then self.master_id = parent_id
    when Kennel then self.kennel_id = parent_id
    end
  end
  def parent_id
    case parent.class
    when Master then self.master_id
    when Kennel then self.kennel_id
    end
  end
end
```

But that sucks too. Could the relation be polymorphic? Then you can leave out the switching.

```
class Dog
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end

= f.hidden_field :owner_id
```

Just some ideas. Hopefully one of them makes sense to you...

Comment: Thanks! all good ideas and very helpful! I had looked into making the relationship polymorphic BUT it's possible, and often likely, that a Dog will belong to BOTH a Kennel AND a Master...and I'm not sure if that's possible with polymorphism?!?

Comment: attempting to pass another hash as in your 2nd suggestion (`:foreign_key => :master_id`) but I'm getting `undefined method 'foreign_key' for #<Dog:0x00000103406f60>` ?!? Shouldn't "`:master_id`" replace every occurrence of "`foreign_key`" verbatim in the partial? Instead it appears to be turning `:foreign_key` into some kind of method?!? sigh...

Comment: ah... `:foreign_key` becomes a LOCAL variable `foreign_key` in the partial.. so removed the ":" in the partial and now it's working. <rant>This is one of those cases where the flexibility of Ruby & Rails actually makes it harder (in many ways) for someone like me to learn. There are so many ways to write something that I don't know what the 'rules' actually are...as every time I learn one it seems to get broken... </rant>

Comment: I agree: The local variable thing in partials is unnecessarily hard. It's just a case of bad API design though. There are more places like this, such as aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, my initial answer wasn't even close. I think what you'll want is a polymorphic association: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations This way, the parent can be whatever class you need it to be.